# Amazon AMC SQL Queries - How to declare a variable

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how to declare a date a variable in SQL for Amazon Marketing Cloud? The query UI for AMC uses syntax specific to Amazon and I cannot find this in the documentation or instructional queries.

I'm trying to do something like this, adding a couple date parameters I can then re-use across a few different tables and date fields:

```
declare start_date date constant cast('2022-6-1' as date)
select 
    click_date, 
    sum(clicks) as clicks
from dsp_clicks
where click_date > start_date
group by click_date
```

Comment: I don't know about other dbms, but in SQL-Server a variable needs to start with `@`, but I think there's another problem with your query, you don't assign a value to your variable.

Comment: Yeah, this is a proprietary Amazon SQL variant that seems to be sort of like postgre. The syntax above was just a guess, this system doesn't seem to accept the declare function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I’m learning this db myself and just stumbled upon your question here. It’s probably too late and I’m not great at general SQL as this is my first time really trying to learn it for work but it should go something like this if you’re just looking to gain a useable or custom date:
CAST(campaign_start_date AS DATE)>CAST(‘2022-02-02’ AS DATE)
I hope this helps.